# What is the latin learning method of the former Vatican latinist Reginald Foster?

Tags: contemporary-latin, teaching-method

I can understand that many see [Reginald Foster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reginald_Foster_(Latinist)) as an iconic latin teacher. 
Se also [other background article](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/05/29/world/the-saturday-profile-forget-hic-haec-hoc-try-o-tempora-o-lingua.html)

Especially due to his career as the Popes own latinist in the Vatican, as described in [this article](https://www.newcriterion.com/issues/2017/3/the-vaticanas-latinist) in [The New Criterion](https://www.newcriterion.com).

He also appeared [in this 2010 tv show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inQ6CWx7V2c) as "The Latin King", where learning latin from Reginald Foster is compared to learning painting from Picasso or learning music from Mozart.

He is also know from appearing in [Bill Mahers documentary about religion, called "Religulous"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExElEMpJN3M)  where he made some very bold quotes about the Vatican.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZLcWl_NCMY) of him teaching a class filled with many of his former students

Previously he also appeared regularly in the [Vatican Radio show](http://www.frcoulter.com/latin/latinlover/index.html) called "Latin Lover" where he made on the fly translations of various sentences.

Lately he published a book about latin named [Ossa Latinitas Sola, The mere bones of Latin](http://thelatinlanguage.org/ossa/)

But what is his concrete method for learning latin and how does it differ from traditional methods?

Comment: It is "Latinitatis", of course.

Comment: Okay, but could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Genitive case latinitatis "of Latin".

Comment: I was more looking for answers from people who have been on his famous Latin courses or have read his latest book. And on that basis give some answers/comments about his method in more details.

Answer (score 4):

I found some kind of an answer in this lenghty review of Reginald Foster's book by Michael Fontaine:

Here he argues that the ways of learning latin can be dividin into
**The Living Tradition** vs. **The Philological Tradition**, 
where Reginald Foster belongs to the first.

The 2 ways are described like this:

**The Living Tradition**

> "The living tradition, like bodybuilders, aims to increase mass
>   overall before refining the fat-muscle mix later on. Instead of
>   commentaries, it favors dictionaries, synonyms, hacks, puns,
>   contemporary English, and extensive reading."

> [Reginald Foster] is in the business of teaching us the whole language, not how to
>   prepare ourselves to just read chunks of Virgil or Julius Caesar. Make
>   no mistake: 99.9% of the book is solid classical or Christian Latin
>   that Erasmus or Cicero would have recognized immediately. But Foster
>   insists, rightly, that anyone who wants to know Latin needs to know
>   its vocabulary. As he points out, this method is like learning the
>   piano: “This is the way a new pianist slowly grows in acquaintance
>   with notes, keys, combinations, harmonies, rhythms, scales — the whole
>   reality.”

**The Philological Tradition**

> "Philology likes things lean and mean from the get-go, so it uses
>   commentaries extensively and favors close reading — arguably, because
>   it has to; the pace is glacial, so students can comment on individual
>   words or maybe a sentence."

https://medium.com/hack-your-latin/thats-latin-a-review-of-afb3bdd10711